# Non-standard evaluation in dplyr when using dots for variable number of arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

I am trying to write a function that can be used within a dplyr pipeline. It should take an arbitrary number of columns as arguments, and replace certain substrings in only those columns. Below is a simple example of what I have so far.

```
library(tidyverse)

tib <- tibble(
  x = c("cats and dogs", "foxes and hounds"),
  y = c("whales and dolphins", "cats and foxes"),
  z = c("dogs and geese", "cats and mice")
)

filter_words <- function(.data, ...) {
  words_to_filter <- c("cat", "dog")

  .data %>% mutate(
    across(..., ~ gsub(
        paste0(words_to_filter, collapse = "|"),
        "#@!*", ., perl = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}

filtered_tib <- tib %>%
  filter_words(x, y)
```

If this worked I would expect:

```
x                 y                    z
#@!*s and #@!*s   whales and dolphins  dogs and geese
foxes and hounds  #@!*s and foxes      cats and mice
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: Can't splice an object of type `closure` because it is not a vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Called from: signal_abort(cnd)
```

I have tried numerous combinations of non-standard evaluation, as gleaned from the tidyverse [docs](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html#patterns-for-multiple-arguments) and many questions on SO, and have seen almost as many different errors! Would anyone be able to help get this working? It *does* work if I replace the dots with `everything()`, but that does not fit my use case to only filter certain columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your function, `across(...,` should instead be `across(c(...),`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
sessionInfo()$otherPkgs$dplyr$Version
#> [1] "1.0.7"

tib <- tibble(
  x = c("cats and dogs", "foxes and hounds"),
  y = c("whales and dolphins", "cats and foxes"),
  z = c("dogs and geese", "cats and mice")
)

filter_words <- function(.data, ...) {
  words_to_filter <- c("cat", "dog")

  .data %>% mutate(
    across(c(...), ~ gsub(
        paste0(words_to_filter, collapse = "|"),
        "#@!*", ., perl = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}

tib %>%
  filter_words(x, y)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   x                y                   z             
#>   <chr>            <chr>               <chr>         
#> 1 #@!*s and #@!*s  whales and dolphins dogs and geese
#> 2 foxes and hounds #@!*s and foxes     cats and mice
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You may use `match.call` to capture the dots (`...`).

```
library(dplyr)

filter_words <- function(.data, ...) {
  words_to_filter <- c("cat", "dog")
  args <- as.character(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`)
  .data %>% mutate(
    across(all_of(args), ~ gsub(
      paste0(words_to_filter, collapse = "|"),
      "#@!*", ., perl = TRUE
    )
    )
  )
}

tib %>% filter_words(x, y)

#   x                y                   z             
#  <chr>            <chr>               <chr>         
#1 #@!*s and #@!*s  whales and dolphins dogs and geese
#2 foxes and hounds #@!*s and foxes     cats and mice 

tib %>% filter_words(x)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x                y                   z             
#  <chr>            <chr>               <chr>         
#1 #@!*s and #@!*s  whales and dolphins dogs and geese
#2 foxes and hounds cats and foxes      cats and mice
```

Comment: How is this different from @IceCreamToucan's answer? i.e. what does the extra code achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest `tidyverse`, the recommended approach nowadays is to use the `{{ }}` operator to immediately defuse the argument to `.cols` in `across`. Something like this

```
filter_words <- function(.data, .mycols) {
  words_to_filter <- c("cat", "dog")

  .data %>% mutate(
    across({{ .mycols }}, ~ gsub(
        paste0(words_to_filter, collapse = "|"),
        "#@!*", ., perl = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}

tib %>% filter_words(c(x, y))
```

You can then treat `.mycols` as the usual first argument of `across` and use whatever `tidy-select` you want. The output is

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x                y                   z             
  <chr>            <chr>               <chr>         
1 #@!*s and #@!*s  whales and dolphins dogs and geese
2 foxes and hounds #@!*s and foxes     cats and mice
```